# Is it possible to modify an image saved in the cache directory without requesting any additional permissions?

Tags: android

I have an app that is not actually saving any images in anywhere besides the cache directory, just processing it and then discarding it from the cache dir after its processing is complete. I need to have the user be able to crop the image that was captured from the front-camera before processing. Is it possible to do this (sans implementing my own cropping method) without requesting the `READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission? I have been checking out the [Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) library but it says that the user must enable the permission to open the Crop activity.

How I'm getting the image:

```
    val tempImg = File.createTempFile("spectre_", "_tmpImg", context?.cacheDir)
    val imgUri = Uri.parse(tempImg.path)

imageCapture.takePicture(
    tempImg,
    object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener {
        override fun onImageSaved(file: File) {
            if (context != null) {
                //this is from Android-Image-Cropper library
                CropImage.activity(imgUri).start(context, frag)
            }
        }

        override fun onError(useCaseError: ImageCapture.UseCaseError, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved. Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }
)
```

Comment: There should be no reason why that library would need a storage permission for a file in `getCacheDir()`. If that library insists upon the permission, ask the author to make that configurable, or find another image cropping library, as there are [many of them](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45?sort=created).

Comment: Ah okay, I was wondering if there was something I was missing in terms of modifying images from within the cache directory and permissions, but I'll just try a different library. Thanks!